# Angular - The largest value from the table

Tags: angular

I am downloading data from the json file using the following code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/data.json').subscribe(res => {
      this.services = res;
    });
  }
```

data.json looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "serviceType": "FixedOnSiteSE",
      "pricingUnit": "Month",
      "towerType": "UserSupport",
      "reportItems": [
        {
          "contractYear": 1,
          "marketMedian": 11588.825,
          "marketMinimum": 9758.67,
          "savingPotential": "None",
          "savingAmount": 0,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 0,
          "currentPrice": 1050,
          "percentPayLess": 0,
          "percentPayMore": 0
        },
        {
          "contractYear": 2,
          "marketMedian": 11659.855,
          "marketMinimum": 9818.33,
          "savingPotential": "None",
          "savingAmount": 0,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 0,
          "currentPrice": 1060,
          "percentPayLess": 0,
          "percentPayMore": 0
        },
        {
          "contractYear": 3,
          "marketMedian": 11669.475,
          "marketMinimum": 9825.9,
          "savingPotential": "None",
          "savingAmount": 0,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 0,
          "currentPrice": 1065,
          "percentPayLess": 0,
          "percentPayMore": 0
        },
        {
          "contractYear": 4,
          "marketMedian": 11803.45,
          "marketMinimum": 9938.65,
          "savingPotential": "None",
          "savingAmount": 0,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 0,
          "currentPrice": 1068,
          "percentPayLess": 0,
          "percentPayMore": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "serviceType": "TicketOnSite",
      "pricingUnit": "Ticket",
      "towerType": "UserSupport",
      "reportItems": [
        {
          "contractYear": 1,
          "marketMedian": 169.8,
          "marketMinimum": 142.48,
          "savingPotential": "Low",
          "savingAmount": 277872,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 5.49,
          "currentPrice": 150.75,
          "percentPayLess": 32,
          "percentPayMore": 68
        },
        {
          "contractYear": 2,
          "marketMedian": 169.86,
          "marketMinimum": 141.14,
          "savingPotential": "Low",
          "savingAmount": 356496,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 6.99,
          "currentPrice": 151.75,
          "percentPayLess": 32,
          "percentPayMore": 68
        },
        {
          "contractYear": 3,
          "marketMedian": 171.59,
          "marketMinimum": 143.58,
          "savingPotential": "Low",
          "savingAmount": 311472,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 6.06,
          "currentPrice": 152.85,
          "percentPayLess": 34,
          "percentPayMore": 66
        },
        {
          "contractYear": 4,
          "marketMedian": 173.18,
          "marketMinimum": 145.18,
          "savingPotential": "Low",
          "savingAmount": 292320,
          "savingPotentialPercent": 5.65,
          "currentPrice": 153.88,
          "percentPayLess": 35,
          "percentPayMore": 65
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and now with the help of *ngFor I retrieve data in a loop and display it on the page in the following way:

- serviceType
- pricingUnit
- towerType
- savingPotentialPercent
- savingAmount

I would like to retrieve the value savingPotentialPercent and savingAmount from reportItems from the element that has the highest savingPotentialPercent value.

it would be best if it could be done in the component's html file itself. I can combine in various ways, but I can not deal with it :( Currently, the data is downloaded from the json file, finally they will be retrieved from the database and returned in json.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Pipe for your requirement

```
 @Pipe({
      name: 'max'
    })
    export class MaxPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value: any[], prop: string) {
        if (!Array.isArray(value) || value.length === 0 || !prop) { 
          return value;
        }

        value.sort((a, b) => b[prop] - a[prop]);
        return value[0][prop];
      }
    }
```

In your HTML

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Max value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="data[0].reportItems | max: 'savingPotentialPercent' as result">
        <td>{{ result }}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-max-pipe-2

Comment: It works very well, with one small problem, why as in reportItems I have anywhere savingPPentialPercent set to 0, then pipe does not return anything to me, as I set it up 1 somewhere it returns no problem 1. On your example, the same situation as in the reportItems of one site I set to 0, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let max_savingPotentialPercent = Math.max( ...res[0]['reportItems'].map( x => x['savingPotential']));
let max_item = res[0]['reportItems'].find( x = > x['savingPotential'] === max_savingPotentialPercent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print `savingPotentialPercent` and `savingAmount` by this way, here `myValue` is your json data,in your json `reportItems` has array of vlaue to access them you have to use nested looping on to do that.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of myValue">
  //main loop to get json data     
    <p *ngFor="let value of item.reportItems">
    //nested loop to get `reportItems` values
      {{ value.savingPotentialPercent }}
    </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do this:

```
    this.http.get('assets/data.json').pipe(
      map( (data: any) => {
        data.forEach( element => {
          element.maxValueSavingPotentialPercent = 0;
          element.reportItems.forEach(items => {
            element.maxValueSavingPotentialPercent = Math.max( element.maxValueSavingPotentialPercent, items.savingPotentialPercent );
          });
        });
        return data;
      })
    ).subscribe( data => {
      this.services = res;
    });
```